# Jquery draggable div not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, draggable

I'm developing an MVC mobile web application and trying to implement a simple draggable div
using jquery. 
Despite all efforts I can't get it to work.

My guess is a problem in the script library definition but I just can't put my finger on the problem.

- I removed other html elements from the code in order to be more readable
- Not working on either mobile browser or desktop (tested only in firefox)

The code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="~/Content/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/select2_locale_he.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/onloadscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.clearsearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $(".draggable").draggable();
        });

     </script>


</head>
<body >



            <section >
                <div id=test class="draggable" style="height:100px; width: 100px;   border:1px solid; position: absolute;"> </div>
                @RenderBody()
            </section>


    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does any of those libraries enable touch events in `jquery-ui`..? if not, look into http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either. By the way it's not working either on mobile browser or desktop

Comment: do you have any errors in console..?

Comment: Instead of loading too many libraries all together, just add the libraries required for the functionality, i.e: jquery,jquery-ui & touch punch and try achieving the functionality. Later include the rest. In you dump everything at once you might not know where it is going wring.

Comment: I tried to open a brand new MVC project, added the jquery,jquery-ui and touch punch but still nothing...:(